# moment.updateLocale formats not assignable to parameter of type 'void' in angular 4 typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I'm currently working on an angular 4 application that needs to use a custom moment locale date format (let's say without the year), on this example 'lll'.
On a previous angular 1.5 app, I had this configuration :

```
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  parentLocale: 'en',
  longDateFormat: {
    lll: 'MMM D HH:mm'
  }
});
```

but when I try to make the same in typescript (Angular 4) I get this error :

> [ts] Argument of type '{ parentLocale: string; longDateFormat: { lll:
>   string; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void |
>   LocaleSpecification'.   Type '{ parentLocale: string; longDateFormat:
>   { lll: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'LocaleSpecification'.
>       Types of property 'longDateFormat' are incompatible.
>         Type '{ lll: string; }' is not assignable to type 'LongDateFormatSpec'.
>           Property 'LTS' is missing in type '{ lll: string; }'. (property) longDateFormat: {
>       lll: string; }

I'm pretty new into this, so... where should I look to solve this problem ?.

Answer (score 3):

For ppl who will look for the answer to this question, 
You have to pass all longDateFormat there, not only the one u want to change.

```
interface LongDateFormatSpec {
  LTS: string;
  LT: string;
  L: string;
  LL: string;
  LLL: string;
  LLLL: string;

 // lets forget for a sec that any upper/lower permutation will also work

 lts?: string;
 lt?: string;
 l?: string;
 ll?: string;
 lll?: string;
 llll?: string;
}
```

for example:

```
moment.updateLocale('en-gb', {
  longDateFormat: {
    LT: 'HH:mm',
    LTS: 'HH:mm:ss',
    L: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    LL: 'D MMMM YYYY',
    LLL: 'MMM D HH:mm', // Changed here 
    LLLL: 'dddd, D MMMM YYYY HH:mm'
  },
});
```

Comment: How do you assign your interface:
------
moment.updateLocale('en', {
  longDateFormat{
    lll:  'MMM D HH:mm'
  },
});